# RegEx to match elements in a string separated by comma ignoring comma inside double quotes, curly brackets and square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a `string` value as below

```
String str = {"A":"do not seperate,value","B":"OPM","C":[1,2,"AB",{"1":{"1":2,"2":[1,2]},"2":2}],"D":{"1":1,"2":[{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3},9,10]}};
```

How can I write a regular expression to capture its elements separated by a **comma which is not inside double quotes, square brackets or curly brackets**? I want to match and get the elements by doing something like below; using pattern matching.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    list.add(matcher.group());
}
```

The elements should be,

```
"A":"do not seperate,value"
"B":"OPM"
"C":[1,2,"AB",{"1":{"1":2,"2":[1,2]},"2":2}]
"D":{"1":1,"2":[{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3},9,10]}
```

If the string is something like below

```
String str = [1,2,{"A":1,"B":2},[19,10,11,{"A":1,"B":2}],100]
```

Then the elements should be

```
1
2
{"A":1,"B":2}
[19,10,11,{"A":1,"B":2}]
100
```

Comment: since its a json string you can straight away convert to hash map and get key value pair instead of splitting with pattern matching. Let me know if you need code for the same.

Comment: I agree with @Vignesh_A that you should use a JSON parser instead of trying to do it with regex. The closest regex solution I can think of is `Pattern.compile("(\"[A-Z]\":.*?)(?=,\"[A-Z]\":)");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  }`

Comment: @Vignesh_A okay. yeah can you please share the code for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Since its a json string you can parse it with object mapper and get them as key value pair in a hashmap.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String str = "{\"A\":\"do not seperate,value\",\"B\":\"OPM\",\"C\":[1,2,\"AB\",{\"1\":{\"1\":2,\"2\":[1,2]},\"2\":2}],\"D\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":[{\"1\":1,\"2\":2,\"3\":3},9,10]}}";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });
        result.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
A=do not seperate,value
B=OPM
C=[1, 2, AB, {1={1=2, 2=[1, 2]}, 2=2}]
D={1=1, 2=[{1=1, 2=2, 3=3}, 9, 10]}
```

Comment: But my string does not have ```\```
for characters inside double quotes(```\"A\"```)? parsing to a JSON won't work I guess

Comment: That's just an escape character , pass your string and it should work. while copying string from external source to an IDE inside double quotes will automatically create escape characters.

Comment: can someone help me to get the regex for this? I tried parsing this to a JSON. But for my application parsing this to a JSON won't fit. I need the elements in ```String``` format as they are in the given string.
For example, if I take the 2nd element ```"B":"OPM"``` I need this value as it is.
I need this same approach if the string is something like
```
String str = [1,2,{"A":1,"B":2},[19,10,11,{"A":1,"B":2}],100]
```

Then the elements should be

```
1
2
{"A":1,"B":2}
[19,10,11,{"A":1,"B":2}]
100
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can do something like this

```
public static List<String> getStringElements(String str) {
    List<String> elementsList = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder element = new StringBuilder();
    int bracketsCount = 0;
    int quotesCount = 0;
    char[] strChars = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).toCharArray();
    for (char strChar : strChars) {
        element.append(strChar);
        if (strChar == '\"') {
            quotesCount++;
        } else if (strChar == '[' && quotesCount % 2 == 0) {
            bracketsCount++;
        } else if (strChar == '{' && quotesCount % 2 == 0) {
            bracketsCount++;
        } else if (strChar == '(' && quotesCount % 2 == 0) {
            bracketsCount++;
        } else if (strChar == ']' && quotesCount % 2 == 0) {
            bracketsCount--;
        } else if (strChar == '}' && quotesCount % 2 == 0) {
            bracketsCount--;
        } else if (strChar == ')' && quotesCount % 2 == 0) {
            bracketsCount--;
        } else if (strChar == ',' && bracketsCount == 0 && quotesCount % 2 == 0) {
            elementsList.add(element.substring(0, element.length() - 1));
            element = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
    if (element.length() > 0) {
        elementsList.add(element.toString());
    }
    return elementsList;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).